# htaccess: Remove trailing slash from URL ending with .xml/ only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

I need to remove trailing slash from URLs ending with `.xml/` only ..
For this purpose I've created a Rewrite Condition and Rule which is working perfectly fine for the test link `http://website.com/test.xml/`

Test Link: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=6fe08232-438a-53fa-8f1a-1f7f69b77b6f

The problem is when I place the rule in WordPress `.htaccess` file, it doesn't work at all! Seems like WordPress or YOAST Permalink structure is overriding the rule .. please help!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*).xml/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If it's a problem with one of those plugins causing a conflict, you may want to ask on sister site: https://wordpress.StackExchange.com

Comment: @SherylHohman just need to verify if the `.htaccess` file is correct?

Comment: Question Moved to WordPress StackExchange .. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289582/htaccess-remove-trailing-slash-from-url-ending-with-xml-only

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your htacess file: 
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*).xml/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [L]

If not working then download new wordpress and try in that.